# WPF Radio button hit area

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Hi I have yet another problem with WPF controls. I have a code:

```
<ListBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding mySource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Rabio template -->
            <RadioButton GroupName="radiosGroup"
                 Margin="10, 2, 5, 2"
                 Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedSetting}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding SomeId, Mode=OneWay}"
                 Content="{Binding FileNameWithoutExtensions, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The problem is that when i hit `RadioButton` or its label it gets selected. That is fine. But `ListBoxItem` width is bigger than whole `RadioButton` hit area and when I click on the right of the control - `ListBoxItem` selects but its child `RadioButton` does not. And how to expand the `RadioButton` hit area?

One idea that i tried was to add a `Label` as the `RadioButton` content. It wasn't the best idea because it made my app work slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,5,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding mySource, Mode=OneWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"> <!-- New Property Added Here -->
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Rabio template -->
            <RadioButton GroupName="radiosGroup"
                 Margin="10, 2, 5, 2"
                 Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedSetting}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding SomeId, Mode=OneWay}"
                 Content="{Binding FileNameWithoutExtensions, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You said:

> Unfortunatelly this does not work

Unfortunately, you are mistaken. I have simplified the example and have just tested that it works perfectly (at least in Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Just try this code out in a new project and you will see that it *does* work as expected. Therefore, if it does not work in your current project, then you have some other code that is somehow conflicting with this `ListBox`. Unfortunately, there's really nothing that I can do about that.

Comment: OK, that is true. It works but only partly. Still looking for other working solution.

Comment: *It works but only partly*... in my test app, it works exactly as you requested. I can click anywhere in the `ListBoxItem` to check or uncheck the `RadioButton`. Why is that not acceptable, or can you explain what is only *partly* working?

Comment: I wanted to say that partly working to this problem - it works but not in my case.

Comment: Well if I have shown you the code that *does* work when it's not in a project that has something interfering with it, then what can I do to help? You have a problem somewhere else in your code. It's your code, so you're the only one that find out what that is. As far as I'm concerned, you asked a question which I answered correctly. This question has a correct answer, so you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to let other users know that this is how you stretch a `RadioButton` inside a `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: Then I suggest that you follow the advice given in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page from the Help Centre to create a small code example that *actually* demonstrates your problem - the code in this question does not do that, so your problem can never be fixed from that code. Once you have reproduced your problem in a new, small project, then ask a new question with your new code example. Then we should be able to help you fix that problem. For now though, this question has been answered correctly, so should be accepted.